# Any tool or way to automatically cleanup the indentation in old html?

Tags: html, text-editor

I'm redoing an old website, but a lot of the old html structure will be re-used. Unfortunately I think a lot of it was generated by a program and its formatting in the source files is just blocks like:

```
<img src="/images/hotNews/facebookOver.gif" id="facebook" alt="FaceBook" name="facebook"></a></li></ul></div><div id="content"><div class="horizontalQuotes"><div class="qSquare"></div><div class="qSquareDormant"></div><div class="qSquare"></div>
```

Anybody know of any tool or easy way in text editors to clean up the html structure with nice hierarchical indentation like you would see if you viewed the source in chrome or other browser editors?

Comment: I'm a big xemacs (and emacs) fan, they have an "indent" function for almost any format imaginable. OTOH, much of old, "machine generated" HTML is hopelessly illegal, perhaps this should be just the first step to then go to the grueling job of making it w3c standards compliant...

Comment: @vonbrand you're right, need to be able to read it to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most editors and IDEs should have a function or plugin that does this, usually named something like____ prettify or ____ tidy.

If you want to use an online solution, I recommend [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/). although mainly for javascript, you can use it for HTML as well.

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ - worked perfectly with the html I pasted into it - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In SynWrite editor, just call "Run - HTML Tidy - Reformat" menu item (after opening your HTML file).

[image: Menu item]